# Chrome DevTools Protocol - What Domains Available for Target

Tags: chrome-devtools-protocol

tl;dr: Is there a reflective/introspective mechanism to query live objects for their capabilities?

---

The protocol is vast, but certain parts only apply to certain types of targets (e.g. 'Page.captureScreenshot' will fail on an iframe target). At first, I thought maybe target types matched up 1-to-1 with a domain, but, while there is a Page domain, there is no IFrame domain.

I noticed the Schema domain, which sounded promising if directed to a session for a particular target, but it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

`iframe` is not a target, it has a `frameId` property to its node and not a `targetId` (that happens to also be the `frameId` of the main frame).

Regarding the specific issue you have - if you know the nodeId of the said iframe, do the following (Assuming `iframeNodeId` is known):

1. Using `DOM.resolveNode`, [that is documented here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM/#method-resolveNode) get the `objectId` of said iframe.
2. Using `Runtime.callFunctionOn`, [like documented here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/#method-callFunctionOn) with the `objectId` of the iframe, run a function returning the boundaries of the iframe (using `getBoundingClientRect` [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).
3. Using `Page.captureScreenshot` [as CDP defines here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-captureScreenshot), you can now set the `clip` argument to a `Viewport` you can calculate easily from the info we got back last time (we just need **x**, **y**, **width** and **height**.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up moving to Playwright (as suggested by the DevTools docs), which is higher level and supports other browsers as well. I appreciate the solution to the particular example, but my question is really whether one can query live objects about their capabilities and avoid having to piece that info together from docs and other outside sources. I upvoted your answer and updated the question.